# Argument passing in R to functions of several real variables

Tags: r

I'm a newcomer to R and need to solve a multi-objective optimization problem (MOOP). I've imported the mco package, defined my functions and checked the nsga2 function. The thing is that I have not found the proper way to bind the parameters in the function definitions (formal parameters) and those in the invocations (actual parameters) when the former match with a numeric variable.

I have the following code:

```
funct_set <- function (x1,x2,x3) {
  f <- numeric(2)
  f[1] <- min(-5*x1 - 2*x2 - 8*x3)
  f[2] <- min(1000*x1 + 8000*x2 + 12000*x3)
  return (f);
}

restrictions <- function (x1,x2,x3) {
  restrictions <- numeric(3)
  restrictions[1] <- (x1 + x2 + x3 <= 30)
  restrictions[2] <- (x1 + x2 + x3 > 0)
  restrictions[3] <- (2*x1 + 3*x2 + 1.5*x3 <= 45)
  return (restrictions);
}

optimization <- nsga2(funct_set('x1', 'x2', 'x3'),
                      constraints = restrictions('x1', 'x2', 'x3'),
                      2, 2,
                      NULL,
                      generations=150,
                      popsize=100,
                      cprob=0.7,
                      cdist=20,
                      mprob=0.2,
                      mdist=20,
                      lower.bounds=rep(-5, 2),
                      upper.bounds=rep(10, 2)
                      );
```

However, this led to R considering that 'x1','x2' and 'x3' are not numbers:
`Error in x1 + x2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

What is the correct way to pass those parameters?

Comment: Just remove the `('x1', 'x2', 'x3')` (two times).

Comment: After both deletions, I come across another error: ```Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : argument "x3" is missing, with no default```

Comment: That's because the input dimension is 3 and you set it to 2. Replace the first "2" (just after `constraints`) with `3`.Also `lower.bounds` and `upper.bounds` should have length 3, not 2.

Comment: Unfortunately, after changing those 3 parameters, the same problem persists. However, if I get rid of the ```NULL```, I get the same error but featuring x2: ```Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : argument "x2" is missing, with no default```

Comment: Ok, wait, I will write an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several problems with your code:

- the function to be minimized and the constraints function must take a vector as argument, and you just have to pass their names in `nsga2`
- you have to set `idim` to 3, the number of parameters
- `lower.bounds` and `upper.bounds` must have length `idim`
- you have to set `cdim` to 3, the number of constraints
- I don't know why you set a `NULL` argument

Below is the corrected code, it works.

```
library(mco)

funct_set <- function (x) {
  x1 <- x[1]; x2 <- x[2]; x3 <- x[3]
  f <- numeric(2)
  f[1] <- min(-5*x1 - 2*x2 - 8*x3)
  f[2] <- min(1000*x1 + 8000*x2 + 12000*x3)
  return (f);
}

restrictions <- function (x) {
  x1 <- x[1]; x2 <- x[2]; x3 <- x[3]
  restrictions <- logical(3)
  restrictions[1] <- (x1 + x2 + x3 <= 30)
  restrictions[2] <- (x1 + x2 + x3 > 0)
  restrictions[3] <- (2*x1 + 3*x2 + 1.5*x3 <= 45)
  return (restrictions);
}

optimization <- nsga2(funct_set, idim = 3, odim = 2,
                      constraints = restrictions, cdim = 3,
                      generations=150,
                      popsize=100,
                      cprob=0.7,
                      cdist=20,
                      mprob=0.2,
                      mdist=20,
                      lower.bounds=rep(-5, 3),
                      upper.bounds=rep(10, 3)
)
```

Comment: Laurent: Great answer! I am working on a similar question - can you please take a look at if you have some time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68324822/correctly-specifying-logical-conditions-in-r thank you so much!