# R : Function is returning Unused Arguments

Tags: r, function, loops, optimization, dplyr

I am working with R. I am learning about optimization and trying to follow the instructions from the following references: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pso/versions/1.0.3/topics/psoptim and https://rpubs.com/Argaadya/intro-PSO

For this example, I first generate some random data:

```
#load libraries
library(dplyr)


# create some data for this example
a1 = rnorm(1000,100,10)
b1 = rnorm(1000,100,5)
c1 = sample.int(1000, 1000, replace = TRUE)
train_data = data.frame(a1,b1,c1)
```

From here, I define the function that I want to optimize ("fitness"). This function takes 7 inputs and calculates a "total" mean (a single scalar value). The inputs required for this function are:

- "random_1" (between 80 and 120)
- "random_2" (between "random_1" and 120)
- "random_3" (between 85 and 120)
- "random_4" (between random_2 and 120)
- "split_1" (between 0 and 1)
- "split_2" (between 0 and 1)
- split_3" (between 0 and 1 )

The function to optimize ("fitness") is defined as follows (takes these 7 numbers and returns a single scalar "total" - the goal is to get the largest value of "total" for these 7 numbers):

```
fitness <- function(random_1, random_2, random_3, random_4, split_1, split_2, split_3) {

    #bin data according to random criteria
    train_data <- train_data %>% mutate(cat = ifelse(a1 <= random_1 & b1 <= random_3, "a", ifelse(a1 <= random_2 & b1 <= random_4, "b", "c")))
    
    train_data$cat = as.factor(train_data$cat)
    
    #new splits
    a_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "a") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    b_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "b") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    
    c_table = train_data %>%
        filter(cat == "c") %>%
        select(a1, b1, c1, cat)
    

    
    #calculate  quantile ("quant") for each bin
    
    table_a = data.frame(a_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = split_1)))
    
    table_b = data.frame(b_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = split_2)))
    
    table_c = data.frame(c_table%>% group_by(cat) %>%
                             mutate(quant = quantile(c1, prob = split_3)))
    
    
    
    
    #create a new variable ("diff") that measures if the quantile is bigger than the value of "c1"
    table_a$diff = ifelse(table_a$quant > table_a$c1,1,0)
    table_b$diff = ifelse(table_b$quant > table_b$c1,1,0)
    table_c$diff = ifelse(table_c$quant > table_c$c1,1,0)
    
    #group all tables
    
    final_table = rbind(table_a, table_b, table_c)
# calculate the total mean : this is what needs to be optimized
    mean = mean(final_table$diff)
    
    
}
```

From here, I am interested in using the "ps_optim" function to optimize the function I just defined:

```
library(psoptim)
set.seed(90)
psoptim(rep(NA,3), fn = fitness, lower = c(80, random_1, 85, random_2, 0,0,0), upper = c(120,120,120,120,1,1,1))
```

But this returns the following error, suggesting that there are some "unused arguments":

```
Error in psoptim(rep(NA, 3), fn = fitness, lower = c(80, random_1, 85,  : 
  unused arguments (fn = fitness, lower = c(80, random_1, 85, random_2, 0, 0, 0), upper = c(120, 120, 120, 120, 1, 1, 1))
```

Can someone please show me why this error is being produced?
Thanks

Comment: Make sure to bring up the help page for that function with `?psoptim`. Those aren't the correct parameters names at all. `names(formals(psoptim))` bring up values like "FUN", "n","max.loop".... You seem to be using the syntax for `pso::psoptim` and not `psoptim::psoptim`. Make sure you are looking at the documentation for the correct pacakge. `library(psoptim)` loads a different package than `library(pso)`

Comment: @MrFlick: thank you for your reply - I will review the documentation. I am new to writing and manipulating functions in R, and I am still struggling to correctly define functions. For instance, I am not sure if I have correctly defined the "fitness" function. If you have time, can you please also take a look at this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68280857/r-x-probs-outside-0-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, if you name arguments, you need to name them according to the function definition. Also, the lower and upper bounds are not expressions, but must be constants (i.e. numbers, not names such as `random_1`).

Such constraints could be handled for instance through penalties: in the objective function, compute whether a variable is outside its range; if it is, subtract a penalty from the objective function (if you maximise) or add a penalty (if you minimise).

There are optimisation methods in which you could handle such constraints directly when creating new solutions. One such method is Local Search. Here is a (rough) example, in which I assume that you want to maximise. I use the implementation in package [NMOF](https://cran.r-project.org/package=NMOF) (which I maintain). The algorithm expects minimisation, but that is no problem: just multiply the objective function value by -1. (Note that many optimisation algorithms expect minimisation models.)

The key ingredient to Local Search is the neighbourhood function. It takes a given solution as input and produces a slightly changed solution (a neighbour solution). Local Search then takes a random walk through the space of possible solutions (with steps as defined in the neighbourhood function), accepting better solutions, but rejecting solutions that lead to worse objective function values.

```
library("NMOF")
nb <- function(x, ...) {
    ## randomly pick one element in x and a small change
    i <- sample.int(length(x), 1)
    stepsize <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
    x[i] <- x[i] + runif(n = 1,
                         min = -stepsize[i],
                         max =  stepsize[i])

    ## 'repair' the solution
    x <- pmin(x, c(120,  120, 120,  120, 1, 1, 1))
    x <- pmax(x, c( 80, x[1],  85, x[2], 0, 0, 0))

    x
}
```

An initial solution:

```
x0 <- c(100, 100, 100, 100, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
## [1] 100.0 100.0 100.0 100.0   0.5   0.5   0.5
```

A random step:

```
nb(x0)
## [1] 100.000 100.000 100.000 100.000   0.759   0.500   0.500
```

Running the algorithm:

```
sol <- LSopt(function(x) -do.call(fitness, as.list(x)),
             list(neighbour = nb,
                  x0 = x0,
                  nI = 500))
-sol$OFvalue
## 0.998
sol$xbest
## [1] 112.329 112.331 111.777 112.331   1.000   0.771   1.000
```

If such a method would be acceptable you, perhaps this [tutorial on heuristics](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3391756) is useful.

---

Here would be a solution with PSO, with `NMOF::PSopt`.

```
sol <- PSopt(function(x) -do.call(fitness, as.list(x)),
             list(nG = 25,  ## number of generations
                  nP = 20,  ## population size
                  repair = function(x) {
                     x <- pmin(x, c(120,  120, 120,  120, 1, 1, 1))
                     x <- pmax(x, c( 80, x[1],  85, x[2], 0, 0, 0))
                     x
                  },
                  min = c( 80, 80,  85, 85, 0, 0, 0),
                  max = c(120,  120, 120,  120, 1, 1, 1)))

-sol$OFvalue
## 0.998
sol$xbest
## [1]  98.551  98.551 110.750 108.639   1.000   0.312   1.000
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I never knew this package (NMOF) existed! It looks so cool, can't wait to read more about it. Right now, I am reading about the "particle swarm optimization" function from this NMOF package : https://rdrr.io/cran/NMOF/man/PSopt.html

Comment: if you have time, could you please show me how to correctly use the "PSopt" function from your package for my example? How can "PSopt" be used to optimize the "fitness" function I defined along with "train_data"? I was looking at the examples and saw the general form: sol <- PSopt(OF = fitness, algo=algo,  data = train_data) . I think I understand the firs and the third argument, but I am still a bit confused on how to specify the "algo" argument. If you have time, can you please show me how to do this? Thank you for all your help!

Comment: I have added to the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Just a question - can PSopt accept "constraints", or do these need to be coded within the optimization function (e.g. "fitness") itself? And can PSopt perform optimization on multiple objective functions at the same time (e.g. like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56359838/argument-passing-in-r-to-functions-of-several-real-variables )? Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: @stats555: There is support for bound constraints; see options `min`, `max` and `minmaxConstr`, passed via `algo`. Other constraints could be added through functions `pen` (penalty), `repair` (as I did in the example) and `changeV`, also passed via `algo`. Multiple objectives are not supported out of the box (though it would not be too difficult to integrate them).